# How to test TLS handshake process?

Tags: encryption, tls, key-exchange

I need to test the handshake process of TLS. I thought to use inter-process communication in Linux. Is it possible or not?

If not, what simulator could be used for this purpose?

If yes, what do I need to do to implement this on Linux? Do I need to implement client and server communication as in the real situation?
If I need to make Java app, how can that be done? What simulator or IDE can I use?

Comment: OpenSSL listening and connecting on some port to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Just make sure that there is actually an SSL-enabled server listening on some port? Or list supported ciphers? Is this for monitoring/development/curiosity? (Anyway, I personally like to use the [*testssl.sh script*](https://testssl.sh/) to test SSL/TLS servers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best channel to ask, however - this is how I do it.

Simple information:

```
openssl s_client -state -nbio -connect myhost:443
```

If you need a deeper insight, you may want to create a Java application (this part you may not like if you're not from Java world) which connects to the SSL socket and start it with the following parameter: `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`

This will print / debug the SSL hasdshake and SSL related events. If you want to print out all network events, you can use the `all` value.